# How to prevent Applescript from misreading special characters

Tags: applescript, itunes

I use the following script to create a playlist in iTunes from a text file of song titles, but it does not seem to get titles in my list with special characters in:

```
--selects file to read from and variables, deletes exisiting tracks
set TheFile to read file "Macintosh HD:Applications:Automator stuff:01b iTunes Scripts:SongListxxx.txt"
tell application "iTunes"
    set thePlaylist to playlist "SongListxxx"
    try
        delete every track of thePlaylist
    end try
    set MySongs to paragraphs of (TheFile) -- read artist names (separated by newlines) from the file
end tell
--refills playlist
tell application "iTunes"
    set theTrack to ""
    repeat with AnItem in MySongs -- get all tracks from each artist
        set AnItem to (contents of AnItem)
        if AnItem is not "" then try -- don't bother with empty names
            set MyTracks to (location of file tracks of playlist "Music" whose name is AnItem) --and artist does not contain "Jamie Farrow" and genre is not "Spoken Word")
            --can also modify the above from "is" to "contains" or "_begins with_"
            add MyTracks to thePlaylist

    on error errmess -- oopsie (not found, etc)
        --added bit
        set theTrack to theTrack & AnItem & return
        --display dialog theTrack
        --back to script
        log errmess -- just log it
    end try
end repeat
end tell
```

Titles which in the 'name' property of Applescript read:

```
Caprice (Le Bal masqué)
Desafinado (Jobim, Mendonça, Hendricks)
Sous le dôme épais (Flower Duet from Lakmé, Delibes)
```

My text file also has exact matches for these, so it's not an error with the source file.

Anyway, these seem to be read by Applescript as:

```
Caprice (Le Bal masqueÃÅ)
Desafinado (Jobim, Mendon√ßa, Hendricks)
Sous le d√¥me √©pais (Flower Duet from Lakm√©, Delibes)
```

And so they don't appear in the playlist compiled. Is there a tweak I can use to avoid this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text file is UTF8 encoded, you have to specify the text encoding in the `read` line, the default is `MacRoman`

```
set TheFile to read file "Macintosh HD:Applications:Automator stuff:01b iTunes Scripts:SongListxxx.txt" as «class utf8»
```